# Closed type families don’t work as expected

Tags: haskell, type-families

A couple of hours ago I built GHC HEAD to experiment with new shiny closed type families.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

type family C a b where
  C  a [a] = [a]
  C  a  a  = [a]
```

Now I try to put `C` to use:

```
class Combine a b where
  combine :: a -> b -> C a b

instance Combine a [a] where
  combine a b = a : b

instance Combine a a where
  combine a b = [a, b]
```

Which results in this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‛C a a’ with actual type ‛[a]’
...
In the expression: [a, b]
In an equation for ‛combine’: combine a b = [a, b]
In the instance declaration for ‛Combine a a’
```

It seems to me that the second equation is *apart* from the first one (`[a] a` can’t be simplified to `a a`, no matter what `a`), so why doesn’t it compile?

Comment: Don't you mean that  `C  a  a =  a` to be `C  a  a =  [a]` or  the second instance to be  `combine a b = a++b` ?

Comment: Is this discrepancy intended? `C [a] a = [a]` but `instance Combine a [a]`?

Comment: Ouch. I copied slightly wrong code. Fixed, but the error stays the same.

Comment: don't have GHC HEAD handy so can't check myself right now, but what happens if you put the two clauses in the other order?

Comment: @PhilipJF: I should’ve mentioned that too, right. When I swap type equations, first instance fails and second compiles.

Comment: Are you sure you copied and pasted correctly? I don't have a HEAD version of GHC, but if I make that closed type family a normal, boring old open type family (and turn on flexible instances and MPTCs), these class and instance declarations compile fine with GHC 7.6.

Comment: @DanielWagner: I checked right now — created a new file and pasted code from my question into it (with the addition of flexible instances and MPTCs). Yes, it still doesn’t compile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked through the mail archives a little bit. Unfortunately, it seems that `a ~ b` does not preclude the possibility that `a ~ [b]`, because this kind of nonsense is accepted:

```
type family G = [G]
```

As a result, in instance `Combine a a`, when we call `C a a` to find out what the return type ought to be, no reduction is possible: because we don't know anything about `a`, we don't know yet whether to choose the `C a a` or `C a [a]` branch of the `C` type family, and we can't do any reduction yet.

There's more details in [this mailing list thread](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2013-May/023980.html), which has a great deal of followups (that seem to be hard to find from the previous link) in the next month's [by-thread archive](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2013-June/thread.html). The whole situation actually seems a bit weird to me, though I'm not sure what a better solution would be.

Comment: It seems that a possible workaround is to change the second instance to be `instance (C a a ~ [a]) => Combine a a where ...` (and to enable `UndecidableInstances`). For instantiations of `a` to concrete types, the LHS can then be reduced.

Comment: (Also, I wrote an email to Richard Eisenberg, the guy in charge of the new closed type families feature, to confirm this explanation, since I wasn't sure I understood it perfectly. He agrees.)